# HP Comware 5500 interface status history

Tags: command-line-interface, hp, switch, snmp

How can I check an interface status history (how long a port is down for ?) on a HP 5500 switch?

I can have the current status, but want to know history, to track "real" unused ports.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: (from your logs)

Answer (score 0):

@ewwhite yes I can parse logs, but found a simpler solution using snmp and especially snmptable:

```
snmptable -v 2c -c mycommunity 192.168.1.254 ifTable
```

it gives a table with all snmp details:

- ifIndex
- ifDescr
- ifOperStatus
- ifLastChange

Moreover, I can use `pysnmp` library to have same results, allowing me more parsing / processing.